# How do I move an image relatively on Android?

Tags: android, image, animation, screen

I'm creating an app that works like a level for speeds.

If you go fast, my image will go up, and if you go slow, it will go down (Not to the top, the faster the upper and the slower the lower).

Currently, on every onLocationChange I calculate the recommended speed and get the actual value. Then I put move the image like that:

```
imageView.setY((float) speedvalue);
```

I have two problems: 
setY is in pixels, so it doesn't fit to every screen.

Image moves instantly, I would like it to move like an animation.

How can I solve them?

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the movement of a View like this:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(startXCoordinate, finishXCoordinate, startYCoordinate, finishYCoordinate);

animation.setDuration(1000);

view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Secondly, convert pixels to dps using this code and it will move the same amount on different screens:

`int distanceToMove = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(1, howManyDPsToMove, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`

Comment: First thing works, but second one is not working for me, it converts 760 dp what is where I want to put one image to 2280 pixels, on a device with much lower screen.

Comment: android:animateLayoutChanges="true" is another way to animate things with not so much control but more simple.